# How to determine if an array contains anything but a specific value?

Tags: php, php-7

Given the below array of values, what is the best way to determine if the array contains anything other than the value 4?

```
$values = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

For clarity, I don't want to check that 4 simply doesn't exist, as 4 is still allowed to be in the array. I want to check the existence of any other number.

The only way I can think to do it is with a function, something like the below:

```
function checkOtherValuesExist(array $values, $search) {
  foreach ($values as $value) {
    if ($value !== $search) 
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use some approach using `array_filter`?

Comment: There is a magic built-in function call `in_array`

Comment: @DavidJawHpan can you add some answer that shows how to check for arbitrary values using `in_array`?

Comment: @DavidJawHpan in_array only checks to see if it exists, not to see if there are other values than X

Comment: _“The only way I can think to do it is with a function, something like the below”_ - okay, and? What about that is not sufficient?

Comment: Yep your own solution is the best. just return the false on end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TBH - I think your current version is the most optimal.  It will potentially only involve 1 test, find a difference and then return.

The other solutions (so far) will always process the entire array and then check if the result is empty.  So they will always process every element.

You should add a `return FALSE` though to make the function *correct*.

Comment: Exactly, although it may be a bit more writing, the OP's proposed solution is optimal. It will return as soon as it knows the result. While other suggestions, like array_filter will traverse the entire array, even if the answer is known by traversing only the first element and traversing the rest is useless. Actualy thinking about it, not sure whether the array_filter solution is any shorter...

Answer (score 5):

Simply do `array_diff` to get array without 4's

```
$diff = array_diff($values, [4]);

if (!empty($diff)) {
    echo "Array contains illegal values! "
        . "Legal values: 4; Illegal values: " . implode(', ', $diff);
} else {
    echo "All good!";
}
```

Comment: This same as array filter, is suboptimal. Even the OP's proposed solution is better :)